# ASP.net fileupload really slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, web-hosting

We're currently creating an online music store that allows, only for administrators, to upload songs and previews on website. The problem is that uploading songs to our website take about 3 or 4 minutes. Is it normal? So can someone tell me ways I can tell to the website's hosters to check because our client is not really happy to upload about 100-200 songs to start his website that takes about 300-800 minutes, 5-13hours :oP.

Here's httpruntime we've put in web.config :

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20480" executionTimeout="240" />
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean "download from our website" or "upload to our website"? Slightly different meaning.

Comment: Yea sorry, as I usaly say when I ask questions, i'm french so ... I mean administrator upload songs on website. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is to check the host's bandwidth limitations. Is this described in a service agreement or similar? Ask them. If you have access to the host server you could check for yourself using a variety of speed test tools or just simply transferring a file independent of your application.

The other thing to check is the client bandwidth. What's the ISP's bandwidth (downstream and upstream), any limits or throttling, does the speed vary at different times during the day (or night)? It's only going to go as fast as the slowest link in the chain, and if there is DSL/Cable involved remember that often these are asymmetric and if so are usually significantly slower on the upstream than downstream.

If the host and client bandwidths are okay, then start looking at the application's configuration.

Comment: We're too buzy to check this out today so I will post back how it goes later this week

Answer (score 0):

Your server can handle fast uploads, the problem is with bandwidth.  Internet providers optimize connections for fast downloads and slower uploads.  If you can, offer FTP access to admins to upload their files.  Should be faster than HTTP anyway.

Comment: I understand but for security reason, and easly file handling, we decides to save MP3s to database instead of on server. So we can't do that with FTP

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://serverfault.com/questions/57031/slow-https-file-upload-in-internet-explorer